# How to initialize "unsigned char *" with default argument in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, default-arguments

I have a class with a method with the following signature:

```
void print(unsigned char *word);
```

I need to set `""` as default value for `word`, how can I do that?

I tried the obvious `void print(unsigned char *word="");` but I got the following error:

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type
  'unsigned char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char [1]'
    void print(unsigned char *word="");
```

Since I can't initialize `word` with a string literal who should I do it?

Comment: Pointers shoudn't be initialised that way

Comment: Why don't you want to use `std::string`?

Comment: Do you need to change word inside `print()`? Otherwise write `void print(const char *word);`.

Comment: @g-makulik yes, I need to mess with word inside `print()`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not entirely familiarized with std::string API, and I frankly don't have time to learn it and change all the this code right now

Comment: If you're going to program more in C++, then I would say it's a requirement to learn the standard library and its classes and algorithms. Using the standard library will make your life as a C++ programmer so much easier, guaranteed! You might want to look at reference sites [such as this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) to read more about what's available.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks by the reference, also [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) one

Comment: well, since it c++, you could define a second function void print(), which then calls your 1 arg function void print(unsigned char *) however you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say that this is a "prefix" argument to apply to the printing.

The answer is that you should make the argument `const`, stop doing whatever mutations you're doing to it inside the function, and then use `""` as a default argument:

```
void print(const char* prefix = "")
```

Comment: even if I wrap all modification in a copy and make this argument `const` you answer don't work because I still need the `unsigned char` and string literal are not compatible

Comment: @RSFalcon7: You don't "need" `unsigned char`.

Comment: I do, this problem is more complex than what I'm showing here, and `unsigned char` is not a just whim of mine

Comment: @RSFalcon7: Then do what claptrap suggested, _but keep it `const`_.

Answer (score 7):

try

```
unsigned char empty[] = { 0 };

void print(unsigned char* word = empty )
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, you think its ok to give him a char* array which he can only safely write one byte to?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett: Okay, I'll grant you, since he wants to modify this argument then there might be a hole there. Hopefully he'd only modify it when it actually contains text.

Comment: yes, but then this is no better than having the "" in const memory, and perhaps much much worse.

Answer (score 4):

`""` yields an array of `const char`, whereupon you want an array of or pointer to `NON-const unsigned char`, both the type and the cv-qualification don't fit.

Note also that in C++ `char != signed char` and `char != unsigned char`.

Possibly you mean `void print(const char *word);`, but probably you *want* just `print(std::string const &)` or `print(std::string)`.

Comment: I don't want any `const` types, just an initialization for `unsigned char *`

Comment: @RSFalcon7 You can't initialise a pointer to non-const characters with a string literal (which is `const`).

Comment: @RSFalcon7: "I don't want any const types", why?

Comment: because I'm going to change the value of `word` inside `print()`

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Your `print` function modifies data passed to it?  Remind me not to use your API :)

Comment: @RSFalcon7: Why on earth would a function `print` _modify_ its argument?

Comment: you didn't answer my question, just explained the error with string literal initialization. the only argument I expect to receive is "", anything else is a prefix for for printing (used with recursion). I might change the argument name to "prefix"

Comment: @RSFalcon7: Then the answer is to _not_ modify this argument inside the function, and take a `const char* prefix = ""`. That's _it_.

Comment: @phresnel unless you are planning to actually answer the question, please delete this

Comment: @RSFalcon7: It was an attempt to point you at the right direction. Unless you want to chill away people trying to help you, please change your tone for you are not in the position to order people around. Alternatively, show me your admin badge. And instead of everything, just make use of the site features and vote my attempt down.

Comment: @RSFalcon7: This answers the question. If you've convinced yourself that you need a broken design, rather than following this advice and using sensible types, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @phresnel I didn't mean to be offensive in any way either to order anything. It was a attempt to make easier to future viewers to find an answer quicker. And don't get me wrong the information you give was useful (which is why I won't downvote), thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 void print();
 void print(unsigned char* prefix);
 // in cpp file:
 void print(){
   unsigned char temp = 0;
   print(&temp);
 }
```

This provides two overloads, one with 0 and one eith one argument.

The zero argument one has some automatic storage memory it provides to the one argument one.  Note that only the single byte under the pointer is valid to read/write: without a length, `print` has no way to know any different anyhow.

While there is no array, none is needed for a single element.